# Curvature plane curve after applying linear map

Tags: differential-geometry, linear-transformations, curves, curvature

Let $\alpha$ be a plane curve, whose curvature can be determined using the following formula:

$k_{\alpha}(t) = \frac{det(\alpha^{''}(t),\alpha^{''}(t))}{|\alpha^{'}(t)|^3}$

Let $L$ be a linear map and consider $\beta = L \circ \alpha$. It can be shown easily that $\beta^{n} = L \circ \alpha^{n}$. Thus, the curvature of $\beta$ can be expressed as follows:

$k_{\beta}(t) = \frac{det(\beta^{''}(t),\beta^{''}(t))}{|\beta^{'}(t)|^3} = \frac{det(L(\alpha^{'}(t)),L(\alpha^{''}(t)))}{|L(\alpha^{'}(t)|^3} = \frac{det(L)det(\alpha^{'}(t),\alpha^{''}(t))}{|L(\alpha^{'}(t)|^3} = det(L)k_{\alpha}(t)\frac{|\alpha^{'}(t)|^3}{|L(\alpha^{'}(t)|^3}$

Following @flinty advice, $k_{\beta}(t)$ can be expressed in terms of $k_{\alpha}(t)$. Is there any way to further simplify the expression obtained?

Comment: The norm is problematic because you've only got an inequality to go on: $|L \alpha^\prime(t)| \le |L||\alpha^\prime(t)|$ using the matrix norm. You can relate the un-normalized parts of $k_\alpha$ and $k_\beta$ in the numerators though.

Comment: @flinty Could you expand on how to relate the un-normalized parts of $k_\alpha$ and $k_\beta$ please?

Comment: Now I'm not sure. I suppose the numerators can be written as determinants like here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_a_general_parametrization $\det(\alpha',\alpha'')$ and $\det(\beta',\beta'')$ so you might be able to use the property $\det(XY)=\det(X)\det(Y)$ to see how $k_\beta$ is scaled by $\det(L)$